# Datasheet view Headings modify

Tags: list, datasheet, header

I am looking to modify the headings on a **datasheet** view of my list. I want to do any 1 of the 3 options below

**1**. Remove the headings column. I have tried adding the following code
    
    .ms-viewheadertr {
    display: none;
    }

This works however when you click on a list item the input box is moved to another location further on the right of the screen which is outside the table

**2**. Remove the option for a user to add a column by pressing on the + icon at the end of the table

**3**. make the heading text white and the heading background white.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some CSS that should satisfy Option 1.

```
.ms-viewheadertr *, .ms-viewheadertr {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0 !important;
    line-height: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border-top: 0 !important;
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

I chose to use `visibility:hidden` instead of `display:none`. By doing that there is still the original space allocated to the header and as a result, the input box' positioning will match with the corresponding cells.

**Updated the answer above.**

- With the updated rule the header should have a height of 0px.

Comment: Thanks that worked as you described. Do you know any way I can reduce the height of the heading as it is leaving a large blank space between my text and the start of the grid.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. With this rule the height of the header should be 0px.

Comment: @TomSanderson I would be happy if you could mark it as answer then. Thanks!